# How to get a driver list in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

What is the best way to create a list of all locally installed drivers with C# and the .net Framework?

It should work for Vista based Windows versions.

The list should contain:

- Name of the driver
- Version of the driver
- Location of the driver on the HDD.

Any suggestions / help is appreciated.

Till now I have found a wmi query: that points to the right direction.
[Win32_PnPSignedDriver class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394354(v=vs.85).aspx)
("Select * from Win32_PnPSignedDriver")

Comment: Can you update your post with the information you found while researching your question?

Comment: Thank you for showing you have done a little research. Now, to your comment `this looks quite complicated.`: try to figure it out yourself, and when you run into a *specific* issue or question, head on back.

Comment: It has been downvoted because you are asking people to provide a solution to a somewhat complicated problem that you apparently haven't tried very hard to solve yourself.  It gives the impression that you are hoping they will do your work for you, work you are likely being paid to do.

Comment: Got any solution? I am trying to use pnputil but that doesn't seem to work in C#

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
    SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery(
        "select name, pathname from Win32_Service");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
                "Name: {0}\tPath : {1}", service["Name"], service["pathname"]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of drivers use the powershell script:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_PnPSignedDriver" | Select  Caption, Description, DeviceID, DeviceClass, DriverVersion, DriverDate, DriverProviderName, InfName
```

To get a list of driver paths use the powershell script:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_PnPSignedDriverCIMDataFile" | Select Dependent| foreach {
$y = $_ -match '(?<=")(.*?)(?=")'
$Matches[0]
}
```

At the moment i am just not sure if there are other drivers that this query doesn't match.

---

To use Powershell in C# use: `System.Management.Automation`